# How to determine the kind of Web Service Encoding from the WSDL?

Tags: web-services, encoding

Is it possible to figure out from a WSDL, what is the kind of webservice?

- Document/literal
- Document/encoded
- RPC/literal
- RPC/encoded

If yes, how?

Comment: What tool are you using to do the auto discover?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, you can use the Zend framework's `Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover` class.

Otherwise, look at the **Response**:

- Document style response contains `schema` definitions, whilst RPC does not
- Literal contains `name` attributes, whilst encoded does not

**Aside:**
The pairing is usually *RPC/encoded* or *Document/literal*, as *Document/encoded* is not WS-I compliant. *Document/literal* is most common of all types.

So for example these are both of type *Document/literal* as they contain both `schema` definitions and `name` attributes:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl
- https://webapi.allegro.pl/uploader.php?wsdl

**Reference:**
Examples of all three valid combinations: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27H_6.2.0/fa2ws_ovw_soap_syntax_lit.html

Comment: I am using Java to consume the webservices.

Comment: And "not common" is not enough for me to eliminate "Doc/encoded"

Comment: The Document/encoded combo is non-compliant. Document/literal is most common out of the three valid combinations.

Comment: That may be so, but it's irrelevant to my question - I am not trying to do a "best guess"  based on probability

Comment: It was just an aside/FYI, really. You can use the first two bullet points to deduce exactly which your dealing with.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27H_6.2.0/fa2ws_ovw_soap_syntax_lit.html

Comment: How did you get on?